# Making a mesh partly semi-transparent and still receive correct shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am creating some game like Minecraft, but not in a first person view, but rather in a top down view.

[image: Screenshot 1]

The problem is, as soon as you dig inside something, the player (obviously) can't be seen anymore. Because of that, I tried to make a shader that cuts a hole in a mesh, so that you can see where you are underground.

I'm really bad with shaders, but somehow I managed to code something like that.

[image: Screenshot 2]

As you can see here, the hole cuts also a hole in the shadow casting, although the actual ceiling should still be there.

This is the code:

```
Shader "Custom/NewSurfaceShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _Cutoff("Cutoff", Range(0, 1)) = 0.5

        _PlayerPosition ("Player Position", Vector) = (0, 0, 0)
    }
    SubShader
    {  
        Tags { "Queue"="Geometry" }

        CGPROGRAM

            #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows addshadow
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            struct Input
            {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
                float3 worldPos;
            };

            half _Glossiness;
            half _Metallic;
            fixed4 _Color;
            fixed3 _PlayerPosition;

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
            {
                fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                o.Metallic = _Metallic;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
                 if (distance(IN.worldPos.xz, _PlayerPosition.xz) < 7 && IN.worldPos.y > _PlayerPosition.y)
                {            
                    clip(-1);
                }
            }

        ENDCG

        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}

        CGPROGRAM

            #pragma surface surf Standard addshadow alpha:fade
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            struct Input
            {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
                float3 worldPos;
            };

            half _Glossiness;
            half _Metallic;
            fixed4 _Color;
            fixed3 _PlayerPosition;

            void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
            {
                fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                o.Metallic = 0;
                o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
                 if (distance(IN.worldPos.xz, _PlayerPosition.xz) < 7 && IN.worldPos.y > _PlayerPosition.y)
                {    
                    o.Albedo *= 0;
                    o.Alpha = 0.2;
                }
                else
                {
                    discard;
                }
            }

        ENDCG

    }
    FallBack Off
}
```

Is there a way to cast a shadow without that see-through hole? And is there an overall better way to write such a shader somehow?

Would be grateful for any answers, cheers!

Comment: Ah, I see you're on a [holy grail](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/164537/75627) quest.